# More concise version of max/min without the block

Tags: ruby

I normally do `['abc', 'defg'].max{|a, b| a.length <=> b.length}`, but this seems like a lot of extra typing to compare the results of the same method on both objects.

Is there a more concise way, to do something like `['abc', 'defg'].max(:length)`, which would run a given method on each object for the comparison?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
['abcd', 'def'].max_by &:length
```

Answer (score 9):

This is more concise:

```
['abc', 'defg'].max_by{|x| x.length }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array of Hashes:

```
roomies = [{:name => "Habib", :age => 24}, {:name => "Tyler", :age => 25}]

roomies.max_by{|a| a[:age]}[:age]

=> 25
```