# Finding the element of a Ruby array with the maximum value for a particular attribute

Tags: ruby

There is probably a very simple answer to this question, but I can't for the life of me figure it out at the moment. If I have a ruby array of a certain type of objects, and they all have a particular field, how do I find the element of the array the has the largest value for that field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [More concise version of max/min without the block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087717/more-concise-version-of-max-min-without-the-block)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
array.max_by do |element|
  element.field
end
```

Or:

```
array.max_by(&:field)
```

Comment: Check the documentation of the Enumerable module for more helpful methods.

Answer (score 29):

Does this help?

```
my_array.max {|a,b| a.attr <=> b.attr }
```

(I assume that your field has name `attr`)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for, was scouring the Array api and couldn't find anything, forget to check the api for Enumberable, thanks!

Comment: Always check the Enumerable API. It has everything you need *and* the kitchen sink!

Comment: I prefer using `max_by` because it is simpler to use: the block only takes a single argument and you don't have to explicitly use the spaceship (`<=>`) operator.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks for the info. I didn't know the existence of this method. I will vote up on your comment and answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also sort the array and then get max, min, second largest value etc.

```
array = array.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse

puts hash[0]["key"]
```

Comment: If you're just going for minimum or maximum, the algorithms are `O(n)`. Sorting is by minimum `O(n log n)`. Don't use this unless you need to, as there are some unnecessary performance losses.

Comment: True. Sorting is an overkill just to get max. I added this in case someone wants to get 2nd largest, 3rd largest etc.