# Get the index of an element in an array of hashes with the maximum value for a particular attribute

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes, each hash is like: `{title: xxx, author: yyy, updated_at: zzz}`

In an ERB template, I need to get the array key of the hash that as the biggest `updated_at` value.

I already found about `max_by` in [Finding the element of a Ruby array with the maximum value for a particular attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038993/finding-the-element-of-a-ruby-array-with-the-maximum-value-for-a-particular-attr) and did:

```
<% selected = my_array.max_by { |element| element.updated_at } %>
```

But what I need here is to get not the hash element itself, but its index in the array. How would I do that?

Comment: Just one more step: `array.index(selected )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want then

```
<% selected = my_array.each_index.max_by { |i| my_array[i].updated_at } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a try:

```
array.index(array.max_by { |i| i["updated_at"] })
```

Comment: This is iterating twice through the array.