# How to get min/max value indices in a Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, max, min

`arr = [4, 9, 0, -3, 16, 7]`

Is there any simple way to find the indicies of the lowest x elements?  Something like this?
`arr.min_index(4)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038993/finding-the-element-of-a-ruby-array-with-the-maximum-value-for-a-particular-attr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.each_index.min_by(x) { |i| arr[i] }
```

or

```
arr.each_with_index.min(x).map(&:last)
```

Demo:

```
> arr, x = [4, 9, 0, -3, 16, 7], 4
=> [[4, 9, 0, -3, 16, 7], 4]
> arr.each_index.min_by(x) { |i| arr[i] }
=> [3, 2, 0, 5]
> arr.each_with_index.min(x).map(&:last)
=> [3, 2, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
class Array
  def min_index(n)
    each_with_index.sort.map(&:last).first(n)
  end
end

>> arr = [4, 9, 0, -3, 16, 7]
>> arr.min_index(4)
#> [3, 2, 0, 5]
>> [4, 2, 2].min_by(2)
#> [1, 2]
```